What are the titles, and who is the original singer of both songs sung in Beetlejuice?
I'd like to know the original singer and the title of both songs that are sung in Beetlejuice (1988):

During the dinner with the "important persons"
Close to the end of the movie, during Winona Ryder's flying sequence

I tried to figure this out from the credits; I even made myself a photo of it, but either I am looking at the wrong part of it or I can't read the above correctly.

Thanks @iandotkelly for undeleting and reopening this question!

These songs are:

The ending song is Jump in the Line (Shake, Señora) and
The dinner song is Day-O (The Banana Boat Song)

both by Harry Belafonte.
